# Ambiguous reference in a simple calculation

Tags: swift, modulo

I'm working with Xcode and Swift 3.

I have the following line:

```
let x = playableRect.minX + (hexagon.size.width / 2) + (i % 4) * hexagon.size.width
```

which returns the error `Ambiguous reference to member '/'`

I don't really know why it fails, when

```
let x = playableRect.minX + (hexagon.size.width * 2) + (i % 4) * hexagon.size.width
```

works, and

```
let x = playableRect.minX + (hexagon.size.width / 2) + i * hexagon.size.width
```

works too. The error occurs when I combine `/` and `%` in the same calculation. 
Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: What is the type of `i`? It could just be a weird error if your using mismatched types.

Comment: I use i in a `for` loop, so it's an Integer, while the other values are `CGFloat`. I'll try to cast i in CGFloat
Okay I needed to type `CGFloat(i%4)`. I still don't understand the error but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `i` is an `Int`, and everything else is a `CGFloat` it doesn't know how to handle those different types. You'll need to change it so everything is a `CGFloat`.

```
let x = playableRect.minX + (hexagon.size.width / 2) + CGFloat(i % 4) * hexagon.size.width
```

---

On a side note, the error message you got is weird. There must be something else going on in your code thats causing it to give you a kinda useless error message. I put the same code into a playground and got the following error which is way more helpful.

```
error: binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'CGFloat'
x + (w / 2) + (i % 4) * w
              ~~~~~~~ ^ ~
```